# Entity Framework Core 3.1 does not generate the right data types for properties of entities from SQLite table

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I create a SQLite table from a script using SQL Server data types :

```
(
   ProductId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   CategoryId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
   SupplierId INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   Name NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL, 
   UnitPrice MONEY NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   UnitsInStock SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   UnitsOnOrder SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   ReorderLevel SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   Discontinued BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
   QuantityPerUnit NVARCHAR (40),
   CONSTRAINT Product_Category_FK FOREIGN KEY(CategoryId) 
      REFERENCES Category(CategoryId),
   CONSTRAINT Product_Supplier_FK FOREIGN KEY(SupplierId) 
      REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierId)
);
```

When I connect to the database with SQLite / SQL Server Compact Toolbox, I can see the following data types :

```
Productld (PK, bigint, not null)
Categoryld (FK, uniqueidentifier, not null)
Supplierld (FK, bigint, not null)
Name (nvarchar, not null)
UnitPrice (money, not null)
UnitslnStock (smallint, not null)
UnitsOn0rder (smallint, not null)
ReorderLevel (smallint, not null)
Discontînued (bit, not null)
QuantityPerUnit (nvarchar, null)
```

Data types are correct. Only length of nvarchar columns have disapeared and int have been transformed into bigint for key columns... OK, that is not the problem.

But when I generate dbcontext and entities with the scaffold-dbcontext utility of EF Core 3.1, here is the code generated for the Product entity :

```
public partial class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        OrderDetail = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public byte[] CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long SupplierId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public long UnitsInStock { get; set; }
    public long UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
    public long ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    public byte[] Discontinued { get; set; }
    public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see :

- smallint have been changed into long instead of short
- uniqueidentifier has been changed into byte[] instead of Guid
- money has been changed into byte[] instead of decimal
- bit has been changed into byte[] instead of bool

I am surprised by this behavior. Why isn't EF Core able to generate the right datatypes ? When SQLite Toolbox is able to display the right types...

Is there a way to improve this ?

Comment: Are you aware of the SQLite "type" system? https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Yes I am, including the fact that SQLite does not handle strong data types like others. So ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite Toolbox uses System.Data.Sqlite, which handles data types quite differently than Microsoft.Data.Sqlite (which is used by EF Core)

Comment: Thank you, I now better understand.
At first I was surprised that SQLite Toolbox displays SQL Server data types and not the SQLite type affinities. Where are the SQL Server data types stored in the SQLite database?

Comment: They are not, they are just part of the CREATE TABLE statement, which is stored in meta data.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite assembly does not exploit SQLite metadata to determine properties data types when generating an entity model. That's a shame...
Anyway, thank you very much for taking the time to answer me.